Multiple imputation process
Whether it is a method for dealing with monotonic or arbitrary missing data (FCS or MICE), there is a process I do not understand.
Let's take the example of linear regression for continuous variables:
How does the multiple imputation process lead to several data sets with different imputed values?
Are the imputed values taken from the linear regression estimates? So why are there several data sets with different imputed values?
I assume that there is a random process for estimating different values. How does it work?
Thank you for your help

Introduction to MICE: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v045i03

This is a huge topic. A full answer would require a book, and several have been written.
Briefly: You impute values using a model that is based on the data you do have. That model can vary, depending on the nature of the variable you are imputing and what else you know, but regression methods of various sorts are common.
You impute multiple values to account for the fact that your imputations are not perfect.
To take a very simple example, suppose you have data on the height, age, sex, and weight of adult humans. But some people are missing data on weight. You could predict weight from height, sex, and age.  Taller people and men are usually heavier and there is surely some relationship between age and weight (but it might be complex or nonlinear).  However, your predictions of weight won't be perfect. Not all 60 year old men who are 175 cm tall weigh the same thing.

Thank you Peter. In your example, we can perform a linear regression with weight as the dependant variable. Then, we have the parameter estimates of each variable and we can replace in the equation by the values ​​of each row with missing data? What do we do in the equation to obtain different values ​​for the same missing value? (for each imputation/datasets)

Yes, linear regression.  To get different values, you (essentially) add noise, with the amount of noise depending on how good your model is. Different programs will do this differently. See the documentation for whatever program you are using. (Also, there will be choices for you to make).

This is a point that is not really/clearly explained. Do you have more details on this noise? Do you have any papers about this?

I don't have any papers handy.  But there is a ton of literature.

Thank you for your guidance Peter
